# Implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.3' in new version

Tags: java, android-studio, build.gradle

I am watching this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGcMLu1GJEc&t=4s and the author says to change appcompat to design
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hl1k.jpg)
BUT, I don't have strings like these in my code: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N8bx.png)
What should I do to make it right even if I don't have these strings in my code?
I mean, what do I do if I don't have '''implement com.android.support:appcompat''', but I do have '''implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'''' ?

Comment: It's better if you include the text in your example rather than a screenshot. Even better still, a complete example if it's not super big.

Comment: you have to add all the dependencies first to your build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

Open the build.gradle file for your application.

Make sure that the repositories section includes Google’s Maven Repository google(). For example:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
    }
  }
```

Add the library to the dependencies section:

Replace design dependency with this.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```